# Rails - Select hash element in dropdown from associated model, assign element to field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, hash

**Background:**

```
Organisation has_many :items

Item belongs_to :organisation
```

**Organisation Table:**

```
t.hstore  "suppliers",  array: true
```

This is an array of hashes, which can be accessed on an Organisation page like so:

```
@organisation.suppliers = 
[{"contact_id"=>"4ab343ad-1ebb-4afe-9d48-1814a93c2081", "contact_name"=>"Small Business Pty Ltd"},
 {"contact_id"=>"42771b60-19a7-4692-af81-dd9f9b9362d4", "contact_name"=>"ABC Furniture"},
 {"contact_id"=>"3e776c4b-ea9e-4bb1-96be-6b0c7a71a37f", "contact_name"=>"Bayside Club"}]
```

**Items Table**

```
t.hstore “selected_supplier”
```

This should just be a hash in the form:

```
@item.selected_supplier = {"contact_id" => "4ab343ad-1ebb-4afe-9d48-1814a93c2081", "contact_name"=>"Small Business Pty Ltd"}
```

Note: only one hash, not an array of hashes.

I’m able to display the `@organisation.suppliers` array of hashes in a dropdown, on the Item edit page, like so:

```
<%= f.select :selected_supplier, options_for_select(@item.organisation.suppliers.collect {|x| [x['contact_name'], x['contact_id']] })%>
```

**Question 1:** How can I select in the edit.html.erb view, one of the `@organisation.suppliers`, and the chosen hash is saved into the `@item.selected_supplier` column in a hash as shown above?

Printing the `@item.selected_supplier` field to the show.html.erb view like this: `<%= @item.selected_supplier %>` post saving an edit, is simply displaying: {} I.e. nothing is actually being saved to the database.

**Question 2:** How can I then display the same list of elements, with the chosen one selected i.e. post saving?

I can't add a `“selected” = “true”` or equivalent to a supplier in the organisation, as it may have multiple items and each item may use a different supplier.

I’m open to alternative suggestions on how to tackle this problem.

Rails 5.0.0.1, Ruby 2.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :contact_id
  def contact_id=(cid)
  self.selected_supplier = organization.suppliers.detect { |s| s['contact_id'] ==   cid }
  end
end

in the controller, permit :contact_id instead of selected_supplier

in the view
f.select :contact_id, options_for_select(@item.organization.suppliers.collect {|s| [s['contact_name], s['contact_id']]}, f.object.contact_id)
one more thing in the model
class Item
def contact_id
(selected_supplier || {})['contact_id']
end

def contact_name
(selected_supplier || {})['contact_name']
end
end

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but give it a try if you have not tried this.
**Answer 1**

```
@item.selected_supplier = @item.organisation.suppliers.first
```

or for a more conditional select

```
@item.selected_supplier = @item.organisation.suppliers.detect {|s| s["contact_id"] = "4ab343ad-1ebb-4afe-9d48-1814a93c2081" }
```

or

```
@item.selected_supplier = @item.organisation.suppliers.select {|s| s["contact_id"] = "4ab343ad-1ebb-4afe-9d48-1814a93c2081" }.first
```

**Answer 2**

```
<%= f.select :selected_supplier, options_for_select(@item.organisation.suppliers.collect {|x| [x['contact_name'], x['contact_id']] },@item.selected_supplier)%>
```